# Подсвечивание пустых input?

Tags: javascript, html, input

Не подсвечиваются пустой `input`

В чем может быть проблема?

```js
 (function() {

   var insertButton = document.getElementById('insertButton');
   var showButton = document.getElementById('showButton');

   var input2 = document.getElementById('input2');


   insertButton.addEventListener('click', insertFunction);
   showButton.addEventListener('click', showData);

   function insertFunction(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     var inputNew = document.createElement('input');
     inputNew.type = 'text';
     inputNew.size = '10';
     inputNew.value = '';
     input2.parentNode.insertBefore(inputNew, input2);

   }

   function showData(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     var formElements = document.getElementById('mainForm');
     if (formElements.input1.value === '' || formElements.input2.value === '' || formElements.input3.value = '' || formElements.input4.value = '') {
       highlightFileds();
     }

   }

   function highlightFileds() {
     var input1 = document.getElementById('input1');
     var input2 = document.getElementById('input2');
     var input3 = document.getElementById('input3');
     var input4 = document.getElementById('input4');

     if (input1.value === '') {
       document.getElementById('input1').style.borderColor = 'red';
       document.getElementById('input1').style.borderWidth = '1px';
     }

     if (input2.value === '') {
       document.getElementById('input2').style.borderColor = 'red';
       document.getElementById('input2').style.borderWidth = '1px';
     }

     if (input3.value === '') {
       document.getElementById('input3').style.borderColor = 'red';
       document.getElementById('input3').style.borderWidth = '1px';
     }

     if (input4.value === '') {
       document.getElementById('input4').style.borderColor = 'red';
       document.getElementById('input4').style.borderWidth = '1px';
     }
   }

 })();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form id="mainForm">
    <div id="div1">
      <input type="text" name="input-1" id="input1" value="" size="10px">
      <input type="text" name="input-2" id="input2" value="" size="10px">
      <input type="text" name="input-3" id="input3" value="" size="10px">
      <input type="text" name="input-4" id="input4" value="" size="10px">

      <select id="listColor">
        <option>
          Зеленый
        </option>
        <option>
          Красный
        </option>
        <option>
          Синий
        </option>
        <option>
          Желтый
        </option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="div2">
      <input type="reset" name="Очистка формы">
      </td>
      <button id="showButton">Отобразить данные</button>
      <button id="insertButton">Вставка текстового поля</button>
    </div>

  </form>

  <script src="../js/index.controller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: не хватает html кода

Comment: три равно употребляется с boolean, это во первых

Comment: добавил. Да с boolean, но и данную проверку можно так осуществить

Comment: `formElements.input3.value = '' || formElements.input4.value = ''` - обратите внимание что вы тут не сравниваете а присваиваете

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
formElements.input3.value = '' || formElements.input4.value = ''
```

замените на

```
formElements.input3.value == '' || formElements.input4.value == ''
```

чтобы заработало

Answer (score 2):

Возможно вам подойдет такой вариант, что на много упростит ваш код

```css
input:required {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
input:required:invalid {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input required type="text" value="">

<input required type="text" value="Value">
```